# When alcohol is used to sterilize, what about it changes that it can't be re-used?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, alcohols

I read online that when you use regular household rubbing alcohol to soak something for sterilization purposes, you're then supposed to toss it out. I'm just curious why.

Like, as long as there's a lot of liquid still left, why is it not re-usable? Is it because there's bacteria or other stuff that transferred from whatever you were sterilizing into the alcohol, therefore reducing its effective % of alcohol, and that's what's important to sterilize, so once you're below a certain % concentration it's worthless. Or is it because the alcohol has actually evaporated off and what's left is just liquid (water)?

Comment: When dealing with sterilization, I guess it's not worth leaving things to chance, I suppose. That's the whole point, right, to avoid accidental infection? It's like asking why we don't drink water from puddles on the street. Surely some contain clean water? Anyway, this has a strong whiff of being a medical question, and is too broad, since we don't know what or how you are sterilizing.

Comment: I'm sure somebody's taken up your question in a scientific study. However that would probably be more microbiology than chemistry.

Comment: Likely the process is not 100% effective so that bacteria are let around. Though it should be a problem for the soaked thing rather than the alcohol itself. The latter should be able of multiple disinfection as for bacteria are very very small. I would certainly reuse it if confined in a place and having lot of things to disinfect. I have seen hospital staff carrying around the same little alcohol and the same thermometer when measuring T for an entire lane. Besides common sense and practice, it is true that the antiseptic properties, ie igroscopicity of alcohol depend on water content.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems better suited for MedicalSciencesSE, or at least BiologySE.